# Which Pokémon are only available via Pokebank?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am trying to complete the National Pokédex. However I can't find a list of bankmon anywhere. I don't want to look into each entry on serebii or bulbabpidia, I want a list.

A bankmon is a Pokémon not catchable in XY anywhere and thus requires the Pokébank to obtain.

Comment: could you clarify what a bankmon is? a cursory google search reveals little.

Comment: I believe he's referring to [PokeBank only Pokemon](http://www.serebii.net/xy/unobtainable.shtml) not obtainable in the X/Y game itself (including the Friend Safari only Pokemon).

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Krazer is right.

Comment: You can actually get a list on [serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/unobtainable.shtml)...

Comment: Ooh so there is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following Pokémon cannot be obtained in XY without the use of PokéBank:

- Rattata, Raticate
- Meowth, Persian
- Koffing, Weezing
- Porygon, Porygon2, Porygon-Z
- Mew (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Chikorita, Bayleef, Meganium
- Cyndaquil, Quilava, Typhlosion
- Totodile, Croconaw, Feraligatr
- Misdreavus, Mismagius
- Unown
- Stantler
- Raikou, Entei, Suicune
- Lugia
- Ho-Oh
- Celebi (not needed for completing National Pokédex; obtainable by registering with PokéBank before a certain date)
- Treecko, Grovyle, Sceptile
- Mudkip, Marshtomp, Swampert
- Torchic, Blaziken, Combusken (available through a now-ended WiFi distribution for XY)
- Slakoth, Vigoroth, Slaking
- Baltoy, Claydol
- Feebas, Milotic
- Castform
- Regirock, Regice, Registeel
- Latias, Latios
- Kyogre, Groudon, Rayquaza
- Jirachi (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Deoxys (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Turtwig, Grotle, Torterra
- Chimchar, Monferno, Infernape
- Piplup, Prinplup, Empoleon
- Kricketot, Kricketune
- Cherubi, Cherrim
- Buneary, Lopunny
- Glameow, Purugly
- Finneon, Lumineon
- Uxie, Mesprit, Azelf
- Dialga, Palkia, Giratina
- Heatran
- Regigigas
- Cresselia
- Phione, Manaphy (Manaphy isn't needed for completing the National Pokédex, but Phione is)
- Darkrai (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Shaymin (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Arceus (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Victini (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Snivy, Servine, Serperior
- Tepig, Pignite, Emboar
- Oshawott, Dewott, Samurott
- Cottonee, Whimsicott
- Darumaka, Darmanitan
- Yamask, Cofagrigus
- Frillish, Jellicent
- Tynamo, Eelektrik, Eelektross
- Elgyem, Beheeyem
- Bouffalant
- Cobalion, Terrakion, Virizion
- Tornadus, Thundurus, Landorus
- Reshiram, Zekrom, Kyurem
- Keldeo (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Meloetta (not needed for completing National Pokédex)
- Genesect (not needed for completing National Pokédex)

Comment: Do you know if Phione and Manaphy will be required to complete the National Dex?

Comment: @C-dizzle: They are not required.  I missed them when I was adding those notes.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't think they would be required but just wanted to make sure.